# Extracting message type in callback (Python)

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,
I want to extract data of a specific type from the message in the callback. I have only one callback where I get messages from different topics of different type like Float64, Odometry,.etc. Now I want to extract only the data of type Quaternion in side any message of any topic. My call back looks like (although its not correctly working):
def callback(self, msg, arg):
for m in msg.**slots**:
if type(m) == [Quaternion]:
self.process(m)
but Quaternion is not directly recognized. Also I have to dig into the messages like Odometry has quaternion data but inside the pose.pose.position, how to check the whole structure of message for quaternion datatype data.
Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76054/extracting-message-type-in-callback-(python)/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-03**:
Are you sure that you can't find a better/cleaner design for what you want? Seem's kinda odd to me.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-09-03**:
thanks for the suggestion! can you please just write me a hint for the better/cleaner design.I just want to extract Quaternion data xywz (if any) from the msgs, AND I do not know in prior how many topics I shall get and of which type. so I have one generic callback for all the topics...regards

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-03**:
The thing is that I"m not sure why you'd want something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Might it be geometry_msgs.Quaternion?

Digging through the structure can be achieved in the same way that you accesses msg.**slots**, just recursively.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-09-03**:
thanks for the comment. but msg.**slots** gives the sub fields names but their type is 'str' rather than Point,.etc. is there any way to dig out the msg structure with type by type dynamically?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-03**:
There is _slot_types defined for ros msgs.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-09-03**:
yes but it does not help for further digging like I do:
for l1 in msg._slot_types:
print l1
and output i get [std_msgs/Header,string,geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance,geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance]
but when I want to dig using 'print l1.**slots**'  or 'print l1._slot_types' gives error. ?

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-09-03**:
Hallo donhege, thanks a lot, now it works. the only problem was that 'print l1.**slots**' or 'print l1._slot_types' gives error when datatype encountered is simple and basic datatype because it does not have further substructure. now it works, thank you.
regards